# Can gPRC (protobuf) return a null message?

Tags: java, null, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

Our client side calls a gRPC server, which ideally should return a MyMessage response object.

But can this MyMessage object be null? or gRPC cannot return null object because if it is null, grpc will throw exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question, check these [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated) where says:

> Note that no Java protocol buffer methods accept or return nulls unless otherwise specified.

So it seems gRPC can't return null. By the way you can take a look to to [google.protobuf.empty](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Empty) and [reference for Java](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Empty)

You can define your proto like:

```
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service SomeService {
    rpc SomeOperation (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @J.F. but how about if the server is down or the server has some problem/error, then int these cases, could the rpc response be null?

Comment: As far as I know, if the server fails it returns the response code. Check [this link](https://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/error/). "If an error occurs, gRPC returns one of its error status codes instead". And if the server is down then the client generate the error due to the timeout response (called deadline, [more info](https://grpc.io/blog/deadlines/))"By default this deadline is a very large number, dependent on the language implementation".